# eclipse 3.7 properties editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

My Properties

```
#\u6700\u5927\u8bf7\u6c42\u5b57\u8282\u6570(1*1024*1024)
MAX_REQUEST_BYTES= 1048576
#\u7167\u7247\u5899\u6700\u5927\u641c\u7d22\u7528\u6237\u6570 
MAX_SEARCH_USERS_NUMS= 192
```

I can't install propedit which I use in eclipse before to view and editor unicode characters.

Any other plugin can do this?

Comment: There is a generic properties editor, http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/properties-editor , but I don't know of eclipse specific one

Comment: @AurA can't install in eclipse 3.7

Comment: What properties file is this?

Comment: fixed， install from eclipse marketplace

Comment: i prefer write plain unicode character in UTF-8 encoding to properties file, and use my own loader to load properties file.